# Client authentication with certificate, certificate order list or default certificate

Tags: windows-10, certificate

For developing purposes, I've several certificates in my current user's personal store. So when I have to authenticate with a certificate, ie. on my VPN client, Windows propose me to chose in my certificates list:

[Certificates list screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgmGu.png)

My "problem" is simple: actually, Windows displays the certificates in a "last installed certificate, first in the list" way. So he proposes me the blue one by default, but I would like to have the red one at the top (because it's my personal one, the other ones I only use them programmatically). Note: I'm in a professional context, I really can't make the trick to uninstall/reinstall my personal certificate, it could have too much side effects

So is it possible to change the certificate proposed by default by Windows? Or is this possible to change the display order?

Thanks.

Comment: Base on these two observations: my "target" certificate doesn't have a friendly name and it's the only one "Class 2 Authentication CA" in the list (other one are Class 1, other Class 2 types, Communications Server, from external editors), I've fortuitously found a workaround. I've set a friendly name for my target certificate, and now Windows only proposes me this one, maybe because it's the only one of the needed certificate's type. But I'm still interested for a real solution if somebody has a clue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong when I wrote "last installed certificate, first in the list": it displays the certificates sorted by expiration date (ascending) and it seems that it can't be modified